# What is the actual logic of saving a variable in memory of Python

Tags: python, variables, memory, python-3.4

On this example;

```
>>> b = 2
>>> c = b/2
>>> d = c*b
>>> id(b)
1820966944
>>> d
2.0
>>> b = 4
>>> d
2.0
>>> id(b)
1820966976
>>> d
2.0
>>>
```

After we redefine the variable `b` , `d` is still `2`. The ids are different, so we know that both `b`s are different but, if `d` is still `2` it means old `b` is still somewhere in memory. Since the new `b` is equal to `4`, we can't reach to old `b`. We can't say that old `b` is gone because `d` is still `2`. So what happend to old `b` ? How can we reach to old one? It's still exist because `d` equal to `2`.

Comment: Why does `d` being equal to 2 mean that the old `b` still exists?

Comment: Because if `b` is equal to 4, `d` must equal to 8. But `d` still equals to `2` after redefining `b`. So operation on this variable depends on old one

Comment: `d = c*b` is not a lazy computation, it is calculated right away and is referred by `d`, changing `b` or `c` after that won't affect its value.

Comment: The "old" `b` was relevant during the assignment of `d`, afterwards `d` will "remember" only its assigned value - not how it was calculated.

Comment: You are misunderstanding how things work.  Setting `d = c*b` sets the value of `d` *once*, at that moment.  `d` will not "update" if you later change `b`.

Comment: @BrenBarn It makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are assuming that the equation you wrote for d `d=c*b` is what is stored in memory, and that if you update b, it would update the value in d.  In fact, the equation is executed as soon as the line `d=c*b` is executed, and the *value* returned is what is stored in memory for d.  That is why it is not updating when you update b.